# Python 3 Dictionary Comprehension Exec Error

Tags: python-3.x

Can someone explain this error? The contents of DictTest.py are below. If I copy (%paste) this code into an ipython terminal the test passes. If if call

```
>>> %run DictTest.py -m
```

The test fails with

```
name 'keys' is not defined
```

The 'keys' that it is complaining about is the "in keys" part of the dict comprehension. I am using 3.4.1 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit) on linux.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4

import unittest

class DictTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_dict_comprehension(self):
        code = """
d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4}
keys = ['a', 'd']
items = d.items()
nd = {k: v for k, v in items if k in keys}
print('>>>' + str(nd))
"""
        try:
            exec(code)
        except Exception as e:
            self.assertTrue(False, "Exec ERROR>>> %s" % e)

def main():
    dt = DictTest()    
    dt.test_dict_comprehension()


if  __name__ =='__main__':main()
```

Comment: Interesting. It seems to work only if both the code and the exec are on top level, i.e. not in a function. Strange: Even if you change it to `if k in items}` then `items` cna not be resolved, although it can be resolved earlier in the comprehension. Also, seems to work in Python 2.6, if you replace the dict comprehension with a `dict(...)` expression.

Comment: Thanks tobias_k: Is there something special about the way this comprehension is executed in this context? If I make keys a global variable the test passes in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is (mostly) in the docs for exec, assignment statements, and comprehensions.\

Exec: exec(s) is equivalent to exec(s, globals(), locals()).  At module scope (case1), locals is globals().  In function scope (case2), they are two different objects.  "If exec gets two separate objects as globals and locals, the code will be executed as if it were embedded in a class definition."  The following gives the same error about 'keys' not recognized.

```
class C:
    d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4}
    keys = ['a', 'd']
    items = d.items()
    nd = {k: v for k, v in items if k in keys}
    print('>>>' + str(nd))
```

=: `name = value` binds name to value in the local namespace, which may or may not be the same as the global namespace.

{comprehension}: In 3.x, a comprehension is evaluated in a separate context (except for the source of the first for clause -- not documented very well).  So items is immediately evaluated and while 'keys' is evaluated in the new context, where locals only has binding for 'k', and 'v' (which is why 'k' gets evaluated).  For case 2, 'keys' in not in globals either, and an exception is raised.

A solution for this code:

```
d = {}
...
exec(code, d, d)
```

Other uses might require additional initialization for d.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation, it makes perfect sense. My use case falls under globals() != locals(). So, my executable code should be like that of your class C. If I understand correctly, 'keys' needs to be defined in global scope because it is evaluated in a new context (not sure what context means here). Changing keys to global in class C fixes the error. My concern is, if I have arbitrary python code, how do I know what is evaluated in a new context so that these variables would need to be in global scope?

Comment: I believe the doc is intentionally a bit vague about 'new context' in order to not limit implementations.  The *effect* is as if a hidden function is defined, run and discarded.  (Since the 'function' is immediately discarded and never seen by Python code, there is no need to waste time making it to be a proper Python function object.)  The output of the 'function' becomes the value of the expression.  Generator expressions are similar.

Comment: These are the only syntactic constructs I can think of that do this.  Some people expect loops bodies to be executed in a new scope, as in some other languages, but they are not in Python.  Dict comprehensions are a bit tricker than list and set comprehensions because `k: v` is not normally legal syntax outside of a dict display.  So it has to be implemented as `_hidden_dict[k] = v`.